# AssertionError on unit testing a celery task with autoretry, backoff and jitter

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery, celery-task

Using celery 4.3.0. I tried to write a unit test for the following task.

```
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

    @shared_task(autoretry_for=(ObjectDoesNotExist,), max_retries=5, retry_backoff=10)
    def process_something(data):
        product = Product()
        product.process(data)
```

Unit test:

```
@mock.patch('proj.tasks.Product')
@mock.patch('proj.tasks.process_something.retry') 
def test_process_something_retry_failed_task(self, process_something_retry, mock_product):

    mock_object = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_product.return_value = mock_object
    mock_object.process.side_effect = error = ObjectDoesNotExist()

    with pytest.raises(ObjectDoesNotExist):
        process_something(self.data)

    process_something_retry.assert_called_with(exc=error)
```

This is the error I get after running the test:

```
    @wraps(task.run)
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return task._orig_run(*args, **kwargs)
        except autoretry_for as exc:
            if retry_backoff:
                retry_kwargs['countdown'] = \
                    get_exponential_backoff_interval(
                        factor=retry_backoff,
                        retries=task.request.retries,
                        maximum=retry_backoff_max,
                        full_jitter=retry_jitter)
>           raise task.retry(exc=exc, **retry_kwargs)
E           TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

I understand it is because of the exception. I replaced `ObjectDoesNotExist` everywhere with `Exception` instead. After running the test, I get this error:

```
    def assert_called_with(self, /, *args, **kwargs):
        """assert that the last call was made with the specified arguments.

            Raises an AssertionError if the args and keyword args passed in are
            different to the last call to the mock."""
        if self.call_args is None:
            expected = self._format_mock_call_signature(args, kwargs)
            actual = 'not called.'
            error_message = ('expected call not found.\nExpected: %s\nActual: %s'
                    % (expected, actual))
            raise AssertionError(error_message)

        def _error_message():
            msg = self._format_mock_failure_message(args, kwargs)
            return msg
        expected = self._call_matcher((args, kwargs))
        actual = self._call_matcher(self.call_args)
        if expected != actual:
            cause = expected if isinstance(expected, Exception) else None
>           raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: retry(exc=Exception())
E           Actual: retry(exc=Exception(), countdown=7)
```

Please let me know how I can fix both the errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69099778/1199807

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, while I was working on tests to ensure that the celery retry logic was covering my specific scenarios. What worked for me was to use [explicit retry](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) instead of the `autoretry_for` parameter.

I have adjusted your code to my solution. Although my solution didn't use
`shared_task` I think It should work likewise. Tested on `celery==5.1.2`

task:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=5, retry_backoff=10)
def process_something(self, data):
   try:
      product = Product()
      product.process(data)
   except ObjectDoesNotExist as exc:
      raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

test:

```
from proj.tasks import Product # I assume the Product class is located here
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
import celery

@mock.patch.object(Product, "__init__", Mock(return_value=None)) # just mocking the init method
@mock.patch.object(Product, "process")
@mock.patch('proj.tasks.process_something.retry')
def test_process_something_retry_failed_task(self, retry_mock, process_mock):
   exc = ObjectDoesNotExist()
   process_mock.side_effect = exc
   retry_mock.side_effect = celery.exceptions.Retry
   
   with pytest.raises(celery.exceptions.Retry):
      process_something(self.data)

   retry_mock.assert_called_with(exc=exc)
```

In my problem I also was using custom exceptions. With this solution I didnt need change the type of my exceptions.